# Using BERT in domain-specific corpus

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, transformer-model

I am planning to use BERT in my domain-specific corpus. Should I retrain BERT from scratch (pre-training) or can I do fine-tuning instead? How can I add my new vocabulary if I need to do fine-tuning? Thanks!